# Voice Activated Reality Warping

Tags: super-powers, augmented-reality

Okay, so before I start this probably 95% completely opinionated but I would really like some feed back and overall help with this.

I’m writing a story where everyone has a specific power or a gift that is a result of their persona (one could have a fiery will power and develop fire manipulating abilities, another could suffer from mental illness and may feel empty inside thus manifesting black holes, so on and so forth).

**I have a villain who can warp reality: I’m still trying to figure out how it connects to his persona and the basis of how he manipulates it.**

If anyone can help with that as well would also be appreciated.

Bonus point: I’d like to pay homage to iconic characters from media, comics and anime and give him a catchphrase that jumpstarts or comcludes his ability like:

- The Rumor from The Umbrella Academy who warps reality by suggestion (starting a rumor) says “I heard a Rumor...”
- Magane from Re:Creators who warps reality when someone believes a lie she tells and at after they do she says “A lie about a lie always turns inside out on itself”
- Kumagawa from Medeka Box erases reality by saying it’s “All Fiction”.

My real question is how can I give this character a really cool one liner that activities his reality warping powers? Is there any real world sources I could take from? 
I really think it’s cool and would love some feedback on an iconic line the character could say before causing serious damage. Any suggestions or opinions are gladly appreciated!! Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to the site vrfzy, please take the [tour] and read up in our help centre about how we work: [ask] We have a one question/one best answer model here which should be able to be objectivley answered. Soliciting opinions is not on topic, see our [help/on-topic] about that, besides, I fail to see an actual question here. You can [edit] your post to add one.

Comment: Hello vrfzy. I suggested an edit, and did what I could to highlight your main question. As Agrajag pointed, it is likely to be put on hold as unclear what you're asking or closed as opinion-based. If you could rephrase or narrow it down further, perhaps we might be able to help you better. Welcome on the site anyway, don't be discouraged if such a thing happens, it just means you have to try again to get your question right.

Comment: Welcome to the site, vrfzy. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions you have while developing your fictional world. We do not, however, address matters of character or plot; these can only be sufficiently answered by the author. Additionally, questions should have an objective "best" solution; asking for "a really cool one liner" is a red flag to have this question closed for being _primarily opinion-based_. Feel free to take the [tour] and check out our [site culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388/6986).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warping of reality may well be a question of degrees - if one merely changes the colour or shape of a handbag for example, then your reality warper is probably an artist, who sees the world through the lens of his or her special talent and how she would represent these things in oils, clay or even dance. "Just as pretty as a picture" would have to be a good catchphrase.

If your reality warper can manifest things, like fighter jets, dinosaurs, castles, etc. then you probably have a Walter Mitty character - an active daydreamer. "Wouldn't it be nice if..." sounds like the catchphrase of the day.

If on the other hand your reality warper literally changes reality - makes staircases longer, changes the size and ferocity of garden spiders, can manifest ghosts or voices telling you what to do, then it's entirely possible you're dealing with a schizophrenic personality. The problem with such a power attached to such a mind is that of control; a schizophrenic doesn't have complete control over their perception of reality and in many cases when untreated, can't even perceive that there is a problem with that. I can't think of a catchphrase that such a person would have but they would be very dangerous. They would also likely not be capable of existing because if they did, then at some point the world could easily cease to exist in one of their perceptual crises.

Ideally, for a comic book style hero or villain, you'd probably go with the Walter Mitty style character and focus on someone who is an active daydreamer - never really achieved much, but lived their childhood in comic books and novels, and just has an innate capacity to retreat into a fantasy world, only now they can manifest it externally.

Comment: Love that answer ^